# StringTemplate conditional statement can't support similar id>0?

Tags: stringtemplate

Recently I use stringtemplate,I noticed StringTemplate can't support complex conditional，similar value>1 or value="menu" etc.
who can give me a advise how to work?thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StringTemplate deliberately doesn't support complex conditionals. The thinking is that if you need that much logic, you're breaking its strict enforcement of model-view separation. Instead, use a template variable that represents the complex condition you're trying to represent, and pass that in instead, or use a method that computes the correct result.